# Javascript slider in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

A link to the website can be found [here](http://calibredesign.com/clients/borgo/).

The jquery photo slider looks ok in other browsers. However in IE, it shows a black bar under the slider section. Does anybody know what is the problem would be?

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this style

```
.nivo-caption p{
    *display:none

}
```

or if you have an external css file for ie just add it normally, in it.

```
.nivo-caption p{
    display:none
}
```

Comment: nice! don't forget to mark it as the answer to your question if it is!